# Scope of variables in JS

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

Please take a look at the following JS snippet:

```
var MyClass = function() {
    var logging = true;

    this.myFunction = function(logging) {

    }
}

myObj = new MyClass();
myObj.myFunction(false);
```

Is there a way to access both *logging* variables within *myFunction*?

The only solution I could come up with (this.logging) does not seem to work: 
https://jsfiddle.net/x7m3w3gp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code in the `myFunction` method it's not possible to access the local variable from the scope outside it, as the parameter is shadowing the variable.

Using `this.logging` doesn't access the variable, it would access a property of the object by the same name.

You can put a function in that scope that can access the variable, to use as a bridge from the `myFunction` method.

Example of the variable, property and bridge usage:

```
var MyClass = function() {
    // local variable
    var logging = true;
    // property
    this.logging = 1;

    // bridge local variable
    function getLogging() { return logging; }

    this.myFunction = function(logging) {
      console.log(logging); // parameter
      console.log(this.logging); // property
      console.log(getLogging()); // local variable
    }
}

myObj = new MyClass();
myObj.myFunction(false);
```

Comment: Thank you! The getter method works best for me, as the local variable _logging_ should not be accessible through, for example, `myObj.logging`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the formal parameter of that anonymous function you create has the same name as the local variable ("logging" in both cases).  Inside that anonymous function (the one that ends up as the "myFunction" property), the symbol "logging" will refer to the parameter. There is no way to access the local variable that's also called "logging".

The solution to this is to give the parameter a different name.

Note that `this.logging` would refer to the property named "logging", if there were one. In the code you've posted, there isn't any such property.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define logging as a Property of MyClass. This should work:

```
var MyClass = function() {
    this.logging = true;
}


MyClass.prototype.myFunction = function(logging) {
    /*References the logging-Property of the MyClass-Object:*/
    var log1 = this.logging;

     /*References the parameter:*/
    var log2 = logging;
}

myObj = new MyClass();
myObj.myFunction(false);
```

Comment: `prototype` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Though something like this might solve the OP problem, note that exposing that "logging" variable as an object property is significantly different than keeping a private variable in the closure.

Answer (score 0):

This should work;

```
var MyClass = function() {
    this.logging = true;
    var logging = 0;

    this.myFunction = function(logging) {
        var console = document.getElementById('console');
        console.innerHTML = 'logging: ' + logging + '<br />';
        console.innerHTML += 'this.logging: ' + this.logging + '<br/>';
        console.innerHTML += 'var loggin:' + logging + ' !!! <br/>--> var logging scope never access';
    }
}

myObj = new MyClass();
myObj.myFunction(false);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x7m3w3gp/2/